# How to see which images Google has indexed from your website?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, images, search-engine-indexing

Ive got a website that is using lazy loading to load in images (so that the browser dose not try and load them all at once before they are required).

The only issue with this is that there are some SEO pitfalls of doing this, ive followed best practices for this by showing the html markup on the static page and then removing and lazy loading images with JS.

But i can never be sure if its working, is there a way to tell if Google as indexed particular images in the same way you can see which pages have been indexed via webmaster tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out if Google is indexing your images by heading over to Google.com, searching for `site:yourdomain.com` then click the images tab.

This will list what Google has decided to index. Please note, Google doesn't just index every image on the planet and it can take some time. Chances are if Google has indexed one lazy load image, it can then read the rest.

Most lazy loads are compatible with Google, this is because Google is able to read the JavaScript DOM and fetch external resources through it.

Comment: Thanks @BYBE we've also got a tumblr blog running on a subdomain `blog.mysite.com` - when i ran the google search it comes up with loads of images from the blog, do you know if there is a way to do this search for just the root domain ? (Ive tried running it as `site:www.mysite.com` but the site is indexed as the none `www.` version so nothing shows up for that

Comment: @sam `site:domain.com inurl:.domain.com -inurl:sub.domain.com' (first operator statement shows all results on the domain.com, second operator statement shows all sub domains on that root domain, third operator statement excludes all results on the sub domain 'sub' at that root domain) [for example](https://www.google.co.uk/search?espv=2&q=site%3Agoogle.com+inurl%3A.google.com+-inurl%3Amail.google.com). Modify as required for your search.

Answer (score 1):

Though doing a site: search in Google images shows the images listed, it's not an easy way to find out if they are all indexed, as it doesn't have a total count and can infinite scroll for a long time if you have many images.

However if you turn of java script in your browser then do a the same search, you will get an approx number of results shown and you can see the page numbers to click though the results.

Another way to show the exact number of images indexed  is to to create an [image xml sitmap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en), or add images to your page xml sitemap.  Then submit this in Search Console (Webmaster Tools) and once updated it will show how many are submitted compared to indexed. Although it wont give you a list of which ones are indexed or not, it will give you a number